# Find global rotation values of two points using python

Tags: python, vector

I have a pipe object, which is defined by two points. I need to calculate what is the global rotation of that pipe because I want to rotate another object with the same rotation. Because I'm manipulating the points of the pipe directly in the edit mode, the rotation of the pipe itself is not correct and I need to calculate it.

To get the points of the pipe in the global coordinates, I'm using the following.

```
for obj in bpy.context.selected_objects:
    mat = obj.matrix_world
    
    if obj.name[0:4] == "pipe":
        pipe = obj
        print(obj.name)
    
        # Get points of the pipe
        for spline in obj.data.splines:
            v0 = spline.points[0].co
            v1 = spline.points[1].co
        
            p0 = mat @ v0
            p1 = mat @ v1
        
            p0[0] *= 1000
            p0[1] *= 1000
            p0[2] *= 1000
        
            p1[0] *= 1000
            p1[1] *= 1000
            p1[2] *= 1000
```

I have tried to create a vector between the points and calculate rotation by comparing it to the normal vectors: X, Y, and Z axis but still cannot get the same numbers as are in the blender...

If you have an idea of how to do that, it would be great!

Thank you,
Paul

Comment: Look at [rotation_difference](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/mathutils.html#mathutils.Vector.rotation_difference). Maybe `(p1-p0).rotation_difference(p1_initial-p0_initial)`.

Comment: I need the global rotation of the two points creating a vector, not a difference between these two possible vectors. I have tried but found not the global rotation numbers.